# How can I display the name of the user who made an edit in a Microsoft Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I wonder how I can display the name of the user who made an edit (with track changes on) in a Microsoft Word document.

For example, in the screenshot below, the string `15 iterations` was deleted: how can I know which user made this deletion?

[image]

I unsuccessfully tried clicking on the grey bar on the left.

I use Microsoft Word 2013 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How I can display the name of the user who made an edit?

Activate the "Reviewing Pane" and you will see the user name in the "Revisions" section.

> When active, the Reviewing Pane will display the number of revisions in the document, the type of change made, and what was changed. You can also use the Reviewing Pane to quickly jump to revisions within your document by selecting them.
>
> To activate the Reviewing Pane:
>
> 1. In the Ribbon¸ click on the Review tab.
>
>    [image]
> 2. In the Tracking group, click on Reviewing Pane.
>
>    [image]
> 3. The Reviewing Pane will appear on the left side of your document.
>
>    [image]

Source [Microsoft Office Word 2013 - Reviewing your Document](https://apps.kennesaw.edu/files/pr_app_uni_cdoc/doc/Word2013_ReviewingyourDocument_rev.pdf)